# semantic difference between" had wished to " and " wish to have + past participle "

Tags: subjunctives

> She had wished to marry him.

> She wished to have married him.

I know these two sentences are semantically different, but I'm not sure what the exact difference is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this help explain it? "It was lunchtime. I had wanted to eat an hour earlier [at 11]." vs "It was lunchtime. I wanted to have eaten an hour earlier."

Either way, there are two times being talked about. One of them says that the *wanting* happened earlier, the other one *wanted* the *eating* to have happened earlier.

To apply these to your example:

> She had wished to marry him

... At some point in the past, she made a wish to marry him.

> She wished to have married him.

... At the moment of the narrative, she experienced a wish that sometime in the past she had married him. But this sentence is not terribly idiomatic; a more common version would be use simple past tense: "She wished *she had* married him."